# jQuery slider doesn't load images first time site is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using jquery load() to display all documents on my website. My script in index.html file looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main-wrap').load("home.html");

    $('#home').click(function() {
      $('#main-wrap').load("home.html");
      return false;
    });

    $('#wilgoc').click(function() {
      $('#main-wrap').load("wilgoc.html");
      return false;
    });
etc...
```

In home.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'fade', animSpeed:800, pauseTime:5000});
return false;
    });
```

default for nivoslider is (window).load, but it doesn't work when I load home.html for the 2nd time... Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: try to use "ready" function one time. or try $(window).ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page has been loaded dynamically (**#slider** is a new DOM element) so it's not working

```
$('#home').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#main-wrap').load("home.html", function(){
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'fade', animSpeed:800, pauseTime:5000});
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Remove the document.ready from your home.html and keep that inside your index html file and  call the plugin inside the callback function every time you load the home.html as folows (your index.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#main-wrap').load("home.html", function(){
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'fade', animSpeed:800, pauseTime:5000});
    });

    $('#home').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#main-wrap').load("home.html", function(){
            $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'fade', animSpeed:800, pauseTime:5000});
        });
    });
    ...
    ...
});
```

**Make sure you are not loading another full html file (with html. head e.t.c tags) inside your div.**

Can you try this(replace each line):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'fade', animSpeed:800, pauseTime:5000});
}, 1000);
```

Comment: There is no problem with cllick function, it works fine, just the first site view - I tried to add the slider line after first load, but no result...

Comment: Make sure sure you are not loading another html file (with html tag) inside your index.php.

Comment: Huh! Really glad tow that :-)